# Select Pandas dataframe row where two or more columns have their maximum value together

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a `pandas.DataFrame` like so:

| Institution | Feat1 | Feat2 | Feat3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 14.5 | 0 | 0.32 | ... |
| ID2 | 322.12 | 1 | 0.94 | ... |
| ID3 | 27.08 | 0 | 1.47 | ... |

**My question is simple:** how would one select rows from this dataframe based on the maximum combined values from two or more columns. For example:

- I want to select rows where the columns `Feat1`and `Feat3` have their maximum value **together**, returning:

| Institution | Feat1 | Feat2 | Feat3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID2 | 322.12 | 1 | 0.94 | ... |

I am certain a good old for loop can take care of the problem given a little time, but I believe there must be a Pandas function for that, hope someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with slicing:

```
output = df.loc[(df['Feat1'] + df['Feat3']).to_frame().idxmax(),:]
```

This outputs:

```
  Institution   Feat1  Feat2  Feat3
1         ID2  322.12      1   0.94
```

Alternatively you can always create a column and slice through it, but this would require a bit of an extra effort.

```
df['filter'] = df['Feat1'] + df['Feat3']
output = df[df['filter'] == df['filter'].max()]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but this answer is elegant, simple and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Feel free to accept the answer! It will mark your question as answered and reward us with some points too!

Answer (score 0):

You can play arround with:

`df.sum(axis=1)`

`df['row_sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

or

`df['sum'] = df['col1' ] + df['col3']`

And then:

`df.sort(['sum' ],ascending=[False or True])`

`df.sort_index()`